# variable=getDocumentById("something").value losing half my data?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to autopopulate a select box on focus, then clear the innerHTML (except for the selected value) on blur (to keep the list from getting bigger and bigger).

Everything works as expected unless the value selected is two words... eg:"Bath Bombs". If I click the select box again, and select the same option (now at the top of the list) it drops the word "bombs" from the field???

(also, with the code as I have it, is there any way to keep the field from shrinking?)

Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong?
(btw: I know very little javascript or html - I have been teaching this to myself over the last few days)

```html
<script>
 
function prodType(id){
 var targetId = id;
 var select = document.getElementById(targetId);
 var options = [ "", "Candles", "Tarts", "Bath Salts", "Bath Bombs", "Glycerin Soaps", "Salt Scrubs", "Sugar Scrubs", "Shower Gel", "Lotions"];
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
   el.textContent = opt;
   el.value = opt;
   select.appendChild(el);
  }
 }

function clearAll(id) {
 var targetId = id;
 var select = document.getElementById(targetId);
 var svalue = select.value;
 select.innerHTML = "<option value="+svalue+">"+svalue+"</option>";  
 }

</script>

<select style="width:150" id="selectNumber" onfocus="prodType(this.id)" onblur="clearAll(this.id)">
 <option value="" hidden>Product Type</option>
</select>
```

If you run this code... select a "two word" option, click off the select box, then select the same option again, this time from ~~THE TOP~~ of the list.

When you click off you will see what's happening.

Thanks!

Comment: quotes matter.... :)

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do.what does building and clearing the select achieve over using a regular html select?

Comment: Sorcery... lunochkin, that solved BOTH problems at once!

Comment: steve - With an input box, you can put all of your options in one place, and use them on multiple elements. -but- other options can be selected, written in, or show up due to autocomplete.  (there is a reason i cannot turn off autocomplete in this scenario).  With select, ONLY my options are available, but I would have to include all options EVERY time i made a new element.  This way I can call the same function and use the same data without writing 100 lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are updating the option value, you aren't including the quotes so it's essentially being set as `value=bath bombs`. The `bombs` gets ignored and you just end up with `value=bath`. Add some quotes (`value='bath bombs'`) and it will work as expected.

```js
function prodType(id){
 var targetId = id;
 var select = document.getElementById(targetId);
 var options = [ "", "Candles", "Tarts", "Bath Salts", "Bath Bombs", "Glycerin Soaps", "Salt Scrubs", "Sugar Scrubs", "Shower Gel", "Lotions"];
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
   el.textContent = opt;
   el.value = opt;
   select.appendChild(el);
  }
 }

function clearAll(id) {
 var targetId = id;
 var select = document.getElementById(targetId);
 var svalue = select.value;
 select.innerHTML = "<option value='"+svalue+"'>"+svalue+"</option>";  
 }
```

```html
<select style="width:150" id="selectNumber" onfocus="prodType(this.id)" onblur="clearAll(this.id)">
 <option value="" hidden>Product Type</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works, but I don't quite understand the syntax.  (I am a noob afterall) I thought putting quotes there would change the expected output to: <option value=svalue>Bath Bombs</option> which wouldn't work because putting quotes around the variable would turn it into simple text.  That's why I came here though - much appreciated!

Comment: bombs is not ignored, that is seen as another attribute with no value.

Comment: Right, but the browser doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such variant with single quotes:

```
select.innerHTML = "<option value='"+svalue+"'>"+svalue+"</option>";
```